# Completable.andThen results in "other is null"

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2

I have the following code:

```
fun edit(note: Note): Completable = getValidationCompletable(note).andThen(repository.insertOrUpdate(note))

private fun getValidationCompletable(note: Note): Completable {
    return if (!note.isValidForEdit()) {
        Completable.error(IllegalArgumentException("note failed validation before edit"))
    } else {
        Completable.complete()
    }
}
```

in the case where `note.isValidForEdit()`returns false, I get the following:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: other is null

at io.reactivex.internal.functions.ObjectHelper.requireNonNull(ObjectHelper.java:39)
at io.reactivex.Completable.concatWith(Completable.java:1040)
at io.reactivex.Completable.andThen(Completable.java:908)
```

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: Is `repository.insertOrUpdate(note)` `null`?

Comment: You are right, what a silly mistake! I thought I should not even care setting up the second Completable in my unit test since the first one should result in error. Wrong! Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm not sure how comprehensive it is, or if this fixes your problem, but [`RxKotlin`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxKotlin) adds Kotlin extensions to RxJava - it may be worth taking a look if you haven't already.

Comment: Will take a look and possibly start using RxKotlin instead of RxJava. My app is 100% Kotlin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to have been resolved, but just to tie up loose ends, the argument to `concatWith` (`repository.insertOrUpdate(note)` in this case) cannot be null.

Interestingly, ReactiveX seems to have its own `ObjectHelper.requireNonNull` function, but *hasn't* annotated the parameter with any sort of `NotNull` annotation, so the `Kotlin` compiler can't check nullability at compile time.

It might be worth suggesting this in an issue.